# Android text view color doesn't change when disabled

Tags: android, colors, textview

When I call `setEnabled(false)` for a `TextView` object the text color doesn't change. I expected it will be changed to gray. If I remove the line of `android:textColor` in my XML file, it backs to normal.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to manually set the text color to whatever you want. At least that's what I've had to do.

Comment: Here is the solution :D

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color

Answer (score 174):

I think what's happening is that since you're overriding the default textcolor it isn't inheriting the other textcolor styles. Try creating a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) for it and setting the textColor attribute to it instead of to a color.

In a color file (eg res/color/example.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>
```

then in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:text="whatever text you want"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/example" />
```

Note, I haven't done this in a while and I'm typing a lot of this from memory, so it may need a little tweaking. The ColorStateList docs (linked above) have a more fleshed-out example for the color XML file.

Comment: Thanks! Very convenient to have it in one place. Just a side note. Instead of the "color" folder (which is not standard for 2.1, for example) you can put it into "xml" folder, and use it as "@xml/example". Also works well from styles.xml !

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically get the color of disabled text ?