# change button text color when pressed

Tags: android, android-button

I have made my button transparent so I would like to have the button text color change when the button is pressed.  Is it possible to do this using just xml files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the section called **State List** in this bit of documentation...[Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

You can define two different `Button` xml files one for the transparent 'default' state and another with the button as Red for your 'pressed' state. You then define a `selector` which switches the drawable resources in the different states.

EDIT: As per devunwired's comment the Color State List resource is probably more suitable for just changing colours rather than the drawable itself.

Comment: +1 because this answer is mostly correct.  I want to add, though, that you can change the `android:textColor` property in a similar fashion as the drawable background using Color State Lists: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Doh! Yes, absolutely. I should have included a link to that too - I just happened to have the other link bookmarked so it was at hand.

Answer (score 51):

Yes, you can do it like that:

layout/main_layout.xml:

```xml
.....
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="bonjour !"
      android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
    />
.....
```

color/button_text_color.xml:

```xml
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="#c0c0c0" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
   </selector>
```

Comment: where exactly are you changing the text color? you are playing around with background, but not text color

Comment: Not `@drawable/button_text_color`, but `@color/button_text_color`.

Answer (score 11):

I like the solution proposed by Konstantin Burov in the other issue: [Android customized button; changing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color)

You can actually manage more states than just pressed and normal. But it should solve the problem.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Focused and not pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="false" 
      android:color="#ffffff" />

<!-- Focused and pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:color="#000000" />

<!-- Unfocused and pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="false" 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:color="#000000" />

<!-- Default color -->
<item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Then you can use that selector drawable in your button changing the text color attribute like below. Note that the selector in the example below is named "button_text_color"

> android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"

Using the same drawable approach you can also solve the background color of the button. Just remember that in the selector instead of using the "android:color" attribute you need to use the "android:drawable" attribute like below.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Focused and not pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="false" 
      android:drawable="#ffffff" />

<!-- Focused and pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="#000000" />

<!-- Unfocused and pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="false" 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="#000000" />

<!-- Default color -->
<item android:drawable="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

And then in the button itself do, note that this time the selector name is "button_background"

> android:background="@drawable/button_background"

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in your code. Try this:

```
    mBtn = ((Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 ));
    mBtn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBtn.setTextColor( Color.RED );
        }
    });
```

Declare:

```
private Button mBtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set `@drawable` xml resource in `textColor` attributte

Here is example: [Android customized button; changing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```