# Android Button animation (color change)

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to do an animation for my button that changes its color from inside out without any flickering.It means the color should change from the center and the button should be stable.The button should not shrink or fade.The button color should change from the center point of button to the overall button.

Comment: Are you looking for something like ripple effect just like we have for calculators etc in lolipop and marshmallow versions ?

Comment: yes but to fill the button with another color from center of button to the entire button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change button text color when pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335279/change-button-text-color-when-pressed)

Answer (score 3):

res/drawable/effect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/your_red_color" />
</selector>
```

Add `effect.xml` as background of button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/effect"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

Comment: Yes like this.I am new to android.Help me that when a button is pressed the button should change color from center of button to entire button.I don't even know how to use it.

Comment: what effect color do u want, in the button like the example I have given.

Comment: button will be with blue before press and it should change to red .After released it should again be back to the blue color from entire button to center point(reverse)

Comment: this effect will not change the color of button, Its just a effect. If you want to change the color of button from blue to red it will be done.

Comment: Ok how to use it please tell me how to do it.I am just statring android.

Comment: where you changed

Comment: "Add button as background" this means

Comment: ohh sorry, I mean the `effect.xml` that u made in drawable file will be the background of button.

Comment: I am asking for an animated color change but you are giving an normal color change

Comment: The question that u asked is too broad to answer here, although I would suggest to look here "http://trickyandroid.com/simple-ripple-reveal-elevation-tutorial/", accept answer if helped.

Comment: Page is not displaying for me.It looks like an empty screen