# How to add image(left) and text on button

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

How to add image(left) and text on button?

---

For illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"` in your layout xml

you can also do this from code

```
Drawable icon= getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.image);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( icon, null, null, null );
```

Comment: Very nice. Is it possible to have drawable background color change? Because my Icon is white color with transparent background.

Comment: it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color

Comment: Not to worry about that, I'm still trying your answer. Is it possible to set drawableLeft with selector?

Comment: Yes I've got it :) Friend, thanks for the input: drawableLeft, and Selector guide! :) It works like charm.

Comment: "android:drawableLeft.." the d in drawable must be lowercase

Answer (score 10):

```
        android:text="Documentos"
        android:drawableLeft= "@drawable/ic_document"
```

Answer (score 8):

We can also manage the size of drawable while doing programmatically

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mag_green);
dr.setBounds(0, 0, 43, 40); //Left,Top,Right,Bottom
search_bar.setCompoundDrawables(dr, null , null , null);
```