# <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to very simply style a `Button`. I just want it blue with with text when not pressed, and white with blue text when clicked.

I tried to do this with a style and a selector.

In my layout I have this `Button`:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/login" />
```

And in `res/values/styles` I have this `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_textcolor</item>
</style>
```

And of course, the two selectors, in `res/drawable`, `btn_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
   <item android:color="@color/SapphireBlue" />
</selector>
```

and `btn_textcolor.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/SapphireBlue" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

The error I get now when I either run the app, or open the layout editor is:

> <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute

I understand the message, but I don't **have** a drawable, is it is a simple, flat button.

How can I create such a simple button?

**Update** according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color), it should work.

Comment: Create a basic `shape` drawable with only the `solid` attribute specified, set to your target color. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: @Luksprog ok it works now, but don't we all agree it is **insane** that I have to create 5 XML files just to change a Button's "active" color and background? There must be a better way....

Comment: Have a look at Dynamo's answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**btn_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/SapphireBlue" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

**btn_textcolor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/SapphireBlue" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:color="@drawable/SapphireBlue" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:color="@drawable/white" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
<item android:color="@drawable/SapphireBlue" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This is correct, here's why it appears to work:

The background for a view expects a `Drawable` of some sort. Normally, a color resource is a valid drawable. However, if you use a state list, the parser appears to check for a drawable attribute on the item when looking for a background. This is why the `android:textColor` can point to a selector that has (and must have) `android:color`, and the `android:background` must point to a selector that contains `android:drawable`. Because a color resource is a valid drawable, you can use `android:drawable=@color/...` like you normally would.

Comment: @HareshChhelana  HOW CAN I WRITE android:color with hash values like #ffffff

Comment: and looks like latest android versions allow to use color selectors as background

Answer (score 3):

- Background attribute expects a drawable and the drawable selector must be in one of the /drawable folders.
- TextColor attribute expects a color and the color selector must be in one of the /color folders.

```
/res/color/my_textcolor_selctor.xml
/res/drawable/my_background_selector.xml
```

Also, the drawable selector must use 'android:drawable' for selector items (a color resource maybe used for the attribute value since a color is a drawable),
whereas the color selector must use 'android:color' for the selector items.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/disabledbackgroundColor" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/myBackgroundColor" />
</selector>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/disabledColor" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/defaultColor" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

`android:background` seems to accept drawable selectors but not color selectors... so just leave a color as your `android:background`, and use a normal color selector with android:backgroundTint, which expects colors anyway:

**at styles.xml:**

```
<style name="MyButton">
    <item name="android:background">@color/some_fixed_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/background_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_textcolor</item>
</style>
```

(`res/color/background_color_selector.xml` is a normal color selector.)