# Debug : android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is a followup of this question - [Debug NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889056/debug-nullpointerexception)

I have fixed the nullpointexception error and my application launches properly. But now... When I select the "Playlist button" The application crashes. I've researched on this error but couldn't find much. I also tried fixing it myself but no luck. I was looking at the logcat and it showed loads of errors but none of them referred to the code I had? When going through it slowly, I noticed `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView`, form there I went through the list and saw `at com.ascendapps.nexplay.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:23)`.

So I went to my code and check the line, but I have no clue what's causing this error?
In the code line 23 displays `setContentView(R.layout.playlist);`.

My full class -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.ascendapps.nexplay.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my full logcat in-case I missed anything?

```
04-06 17:42:51.774: W/ResourceType(12387): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 72 bytes
04-06 17:42:51.854: I/Adreno-EGL(12387): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
04-06 17:42:51.874: D/OpenGLRenderer(12387): Enabling debug mode 0
04-06 17:42:51.924: I/ActivityManager(12387): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42308b80 time:51348547
04-06 17:42:54.684: I/ActivityManager(12387): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.ascendapps.nexplay time:51351305
04-06 17:42:54.704: W/ResourceType(12387): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 72 bytes
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387): Failed to inflate
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:344)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1945)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at com.ascendapps.nexplay.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:23)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5351)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5078)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    ... 24 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020009
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2126)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:807)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:146)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    ... 27 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:181)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2122)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/ActivityThread(12387):    ... 31 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: D/AndroidRuntime(12387): Shutting down VM
04-06 17:42:54.764: W/dalvikvm(12387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fd7c80)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): Process: com.ascendapps.nexplay, PID: 12387
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ascendapps.nexplay/com.ascendapps.nexplay.PlayListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5078)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:344)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1945)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at com.ascendapps.nexplay.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:23)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5351)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    ... 11 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    ... 24 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020009
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2126)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:807)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:146)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    ... 27 more
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:181)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2122)
04-06 17:42:54.764: E/AndroidRuntime(12387):    ... 31 more
04-06 17:42:56.674: I/Process(12387): Sending signal. PID: 12387 SIG: 9
```

Please help me out, I'm really wanting to build a music player of my own, I've tried searching and trying different things it never works.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#222222" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#d8d8d8" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#d8d8d8" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Did you see this? Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020009

Comment: Yes I saw that, but there is no error in my "list_selector.xml" file? - This is my List_selector.xml - http://pastebin.com/JHtiHaCz

Comment: Check your naming (lowercase or capital 'L') and the location `/res/drawable/list_selector.xml`

Comment: @LittlePlasticSoldier : see [<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913822/item-tag-requires-a-drawable-attribute) post will help

Comment: Yeah the names lowercase "list_selector.xml" and its present in the drawable folder.

Comment: Raghunandan is on it with the drawable.

Comment: @LittlePlasticSoldier : instead of using `android:color` in `item` use `android:drawable` as `android:drawable="@color/from_colors_xml"`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thank you! That helped allot, it fixed the drawable errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/list_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020009

You do not have a resource by the name `list_selector.xml` under `res/drawable`. Check that and fix it.

Edit :

At the last you have

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   7:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

You probably should be looking at the `list_selector.xml` and it says item tag requires a drawable attribute which is missing.

Missing

```
 <item
 android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable"
```

You can check this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Edit 2:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list.

You require a ListView in `playlist.xml` with id as below

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Quoting docs

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code

Comment: I've checked my res/drawable and can confirm "list_selector.xml" is present.

Comment: @LittlePlasticSoldier the second part of the stacktrace says that you require a drawable attribute which is missing in `list_selector.xml` and pls don't post links to external source. Is it so hard posting the code here

Comment: Oh sorry, I just thought it makes it less crowded and long. Wait so there is a missing attribute within the .xml file? By any chance what could it be :S The guide mentioned to copy their code and paste it and  I did.

Comment: @LittlePlasticSoldier the activity code is of no use here while the stacktrace and the selector xml is required.

Comment: Oh not to worry, I fixed the .xml by changing it from android:color to android:drawble and gave it a correct path to the colors.xml with the correct colors. This reduced all of the errors. And leaves me with one error - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list. Which is in PLayListActivity

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But for some reason the listView isn't showing any files (.mp3)

Comment: @LittlePlasticSoldier that is a different problem. post a differen question. The problem is in activity code

Comment: Thanks Ill ask it as a different question as later as I'm trying other ways for this to work.