# Android: Set button text color in style

Tags: android

I would like to create a button style which all of my buttons use, this way I do not need to set the android:textColor on each one.

I have this styling in a file named defaultbutton.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#F3C22C"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
    <color android:color="@color/brown"></color>
</item>
```

And for a test button I set:

```
android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton"
```

The button gets the background color but the text color stays as black.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color

Answer (score 1):

You need to add color attribute to the item tag to set color of text.

`/res/drawable/custom_color.xml`

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
      android:color="@color/text_color"> //this is how text color can be defined

</item>
```

Now set `textColor` to the `textView` of your layout

```
<TextView  ...
    android:textColor="@drawable/custom_color">
```

Comment: So I still need to set the textColor attribute at the element level, which is what I did not want to have to do

Comment: Yes @andrewb you will have to. And if you want to style your button's background then the xml you have posted is right to style background. You need to add it also, such as, `android:background="your_style"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with style:

```
<style name="MyButtonText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/mycolor</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "styles.xml" file, you can find it in "values" folder
and add the following lines to the file :

```
<style name="buttonstyle" >
        <item name="android:textColor" >#ff11</item>
</style>
```

after that when you add button add this line to your button attr.

```
style="@style/buttonstyle"
```