# How do I fix Html.fromHtml link focus visibility problems (in ICS and Honeycomb)?

Tags: android, textview, android-3.0-honeycomb, google-tv, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

To get a `TextView` to display (and act friendly with) Html strings my code looks something like:

```
// itemHtml is a String of HTML defined above

TextView itemContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemContent);
itemContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(itemHtml));
itemContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

If the Html string has a link, `TextView` results in links that are clickable and focusable. When the user focuses on a specific link (e.g. by using the d-pad), the link text changes in some significant way to show that focus was obtained.

The problem is that when I test this same pattern using devices with a d-pad using Honeycomb (e.g. a Google TV) or Ice Cream Sandwich flavors of Android, the link in the text shows no noticeable indication that the link has focus.

I know it is getting focus, because when you then hit enter it does the specified action. You can even move around between various links in the text; you're just left guessing which link you're currently at, which results in a very bad user experience.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there some way to fix this or work around this?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: After going a bit nuts, I finally *thought* I found a solution. However, this solution **only works for Honeycomb**. ICS is still not solved!

As of API 11, Android has a new setting on TextViews for defining whether the text is selectable.

You can set it using `setTextIsSelectable(true)` on a TextView, or define it in the XML layout `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

It's probably best to define it in XML, so that keeping the app backwards-compatible is trivial. Just make sure you're targeting version >= 11, or you'll probably get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The way HTML.fromHTML operates is by creating "spans" with varying effects throughout the various characters of the string. One workaround for this would be to use [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) coupled with another of the CharacterStyles to colorize the text as clickable. The previous span will allow you to register a callback, and this callback could be to broadcast an intent to view a url (which would open a browser).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. As I mentioned, the action (ie opening the URL) is invoked. The problem is there is no visual representation that the link is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The text colour state lists for Honeycomb+ might not set the focused state to a different colour, or you override the colour to be constant.

Check the colors + styles in your_android_sdk_directory/android-14/data/res/

Setting the text to android:autoLink="web" might also help?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to add CSS styling to your html. I know Android supports [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) selector. So you might right something like this:

```
String myLink = "<a href=\"http:\/\/google.com\">your link</a>"
Html.fromHtml(myLink);
```

and find a way to include CSS data to it: (I'm not sure how but I think it's possible)

```
a :hover {
   color: red;
}
```

UPDATE:

I think the answer of your question is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111453/android-linkify-links-textcolor-ignored-css-style-overrides-possible).