# Background around each letter in a word in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to have a black background around each letter (not for the whole word) in a word in a TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by using html in your `textView`.

Put your text in HTML and then do something like this

```
TextView contactWeb1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactWeb1);
String desc = "<font color=\"red\"><a href='http://www.mysite.com/'>Visit my site</a></font>";
contactWeb1.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
```

The above code is from the 3rd link

Here are some related questions

1. [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1529068/492561)
2. [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116162/492561)
3. [Android Linkify links textColor ignored, css style overrides possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7178045/492561)

Comment: I can't use "style" inside that html ? 
I have tried to "tvText.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml("<span style=\"border:1px solid #000000\">bla</span>"));"
in order to put black border around each letter but it didn't work.

Comment: I doubt android has a css parser, so try to use only the ancient `<font />` tag