# How do I make an Android text view look like it's disabled?

Tags: android, styles

I'd like to be able to give any text view the same aspect as if it was disabled.
Currently I am using a style that inherits `TextAppearance` and adds a gray text color, but I'd prefer using something built-in that would work flawlessly with any theme.

Comment: you can set  android:background="#666" and text android:textColor="#333"
which looks like disable textview.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: do you mean that I should customize the colors to look disabled, or that providing no values will make it look disabled?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @AndrewNo No unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android text view color doesn't change when disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342410/android-text-view-color-doesnt-change-when-disabled)

Answer (score 18):

define a selector with a disable like color and use it in layouts like this

In a color file (eg res/color/example.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>
```

then in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:text="whatever text you want"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/example" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

[image]

you can set **android:background="#666"**

and text **android:textColor="#333"** which looks like disable textview.

or any other combination of colors

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

[Android selector & text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)

Basically, you have to use a selector as a color and then define a style that applies that text color.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:alpha="0.33"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

just try this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:enabled="false"    <--- Put this
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: I want to be able to be able to use “normal” events (long-press in my case), so IIRC this won't work. As I said in my question, I just want the “look” of a disabled text view.