# setEnabled doesnt work in android

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
public TextView main_text;//begining of the class

main_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextMain); //inside OnCreate

main_text.setEnabled(false); //inside button handler
```

And now the part of Xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/home_load" >

    </TextView>
```

Why doesnt SetEnable work? It seems so obvious that it should.

Comment: Without seeing more code in activity, it is hard to predict what is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342410/android-text-view-color-doesnt-change-when-disabled

Comment: refer this url

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342410/android-text-view-color-doesnt-change-when-disabled][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342410/android-text-view-color-doesnt-change-when-disabled

Comment: Well, the code is now preety big. But basicly the pieces I presented refer to elemend I want to hide. What other pieces should I present, what can matter in this simple function? Hmmm, in difrent words: I try this code without anything (I just try to hide TextView)... and nothing happens (while setVisibility(GONE) works just fine in the same configuration)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What do you expect `setEnabled(false)` to do to a TextView?

If you want to hide the TextView, you should rather call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

If you want to disable clicks, you should rather call `setOnClickListener(null)`

If you want the text to display in a disabled state, then you need to define the states for the view in a separate XML file.

For example textView.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/enabled" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled" />
</selector>
```

And then in your TextView definition use

```
android:textColor="@drawable/textView"
```

Comment: I want to create activity that contains couple functions like: Show descripton, show contact, show gallery. When I create gallery I add some pictures to the linear view, but when I want to sho descriptin (again) I need to hide pictures from gallery. I know this might be not best solution. I tried wit INVISIBLE/GONE, and it works, but I need sth that is universal so I now try to use setEnabled (and loop throught childrew of linear view), and for now it doesnt work

Comment: You should have 3 LinearLayouts - (1) for descriptions, (2) for gallery images. Wrap both those LinearLayouts in the 3rd another LinearLayout (3) (or FrameLayout depending on how u want it displayed). Then you can hide the entire inner LinearLayout (1) or (2) using layout.setVisiblity(View.GONE). This way you can hide the parent of gallery or descriptions and all the children in the layout will hide too

Comment: Thanx, I will give it a try, and post some codes. Definite +1.

Comment: Jeff, this is not really andswear to my initial question. But You definatelly solved my problem, and my app works fine now :D. I click you answear as accepted. Thanx again.

Comment: I found some interesting behavior with `state_enabled` as well when using them as selectors. Basically ensure that you have either `state_pressed` or `state_enabled`. Having both wont allow the enabled state to even register. Anyone else notice this?

Answer (score 0):

Views can be composed by multiple touchable elements. You have to disable them all, like this:

```
for(View lol : text_view.getTouchables() ) {
    lol.setEnabled(false);
}
```

If it is a simple one since it also returns itself:

> Find and return all touchable views that are descendants of this view, possibly including this view if it is touchable itself.

[View#getTouchables()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTouchables%28%29)